# how to query many-to-many?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I found the following table structures while I was watching ruby on rails tutorial.

```
table actors
id  int  11  primary key auto_increment
name  varchar  30

table movies
id  int  11  primary key auto_increment
name  varchar  30

table actors_movies
actor_id  int  11
movie_id  int  11
```

How do I make a query to select movies that an actor is involved in?

I am not asking for ruby on rails code. I want the actual mysql query string.

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to put your code sample in a code block - just put four spaces before each line of it, and put a blank line before and after the block.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

one thing to consider is that you are going to load the author object (because of RoR models), so with the ID would be enough:

```
select movies.id, movies.name
from movies inner join actors_movies
on actors_movies.movie_id=movies.id
where actors_movies.actor_id=$actor_id
```

Comment: it is incomplete, the best is the next answer

Comment: @Christiano Given the nature of StackExchange, the “next answer” is undefined. Whose answer do you mean?

Comment: @Frungi Probably the most voted one ~ By Andy White.

Answer (score 54):

Maybe something like this:

```
select m.name
from movies m
inner join actors_movies am on m.id = am.movie_id
inner join actors a on am.actor_id = a.id
where a.name = 'Christopher Walken'
```

Comment: Is there  any way to get only movies with combination of actors like IN ('Christopher Walken', 'John Doe') @AndyWhite

Comment: @mcek you can do it using subqueries like this: [pasted code](https://pastebin.com/5P9bw9dD).
Another way is a "Self Join": [pasted code](https://pastebin.com/mTCJAH40).
But in both cases query will grow with the quantity of actors in combination. So they are not universal but can be auto generated.

Answer (score 10):

Simple, just use the combined table to join the movie/actor tables:

```
Select m.name 
From actors a
Inner Join actors_movies am On am.actor_id = a.id
Inner Join movies m On m.id = am.movie_id
Where a.name = @your_actor
```

Comment: Is there any way to get only movies with combination of actors like IN ('Christopher Walken', 'John Doe') @JustinEthier

Comment: @mcek - Sure, just use an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
select m.* from movies m 
inner join actors_movies am on am.movie_id  = m.id 
inner join actors a on a.id = am.actor_id 
where a.someField = somevalue
```