# How do I use my join tables MySQL?

Tags: mysql

*I have 3 tables in a MySQL database,*

Author
Book
Author_has_Book.

*The author has two columns*
idauthor
name

*Book also has two columns*
idbook
name

*Author_has_Book also has two columns*
foreign keys of an author and a book book_idbook
author_idauthor.

I have successfully inserted an author and a book into both tables and I have entered their keys into the join table.

Now how do I use this join table to get all books by a certain author, or all authors for a book? Is this accomplished with joins?

edit: The suggested duplicate is not the same question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explanation of self-joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458519/explanation-of-self-joins)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to query many-to-many?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832584/how-to-query-many-to-many)

Answer (score 1):

It will get you all records

```
SELECT Author.*
FROM Author Author 
INNER JOIN Author_has_Book AuthorHasBook
    ON Author.idauthor = AuthorHasBook.author_idauthor
INNER JOIN Book Book
    ON AuthorHasBook.book_idbook = Book.idbook
```

and if you wish to select any specific author, you just need to mention it in where clause, see example below:

```
SELECT Author.*
FROM Author Author 
INNER JOIN Author_has_Book AuthorHasBook
    ON Author.idauthor = AuthorHasBook.author_idauthor
INNER JOIN Book Book
    ON AuthorHasBook.book_idbook = Book.idbook
WHERE Author.idauthor = 'your author id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select a.name,c.name from book a
join Author_has_Book b on a.idbook=b.idbook
join author c on b.idauthor=c.idauthor
```