# How to get multiple category posts in category page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, content-management-system

I'm working on a custom CMS. My problem is I have a post with two categories 'tutorial' and 'language'. I want to display it as an item in category page.

This is my book_category table
[image]

and this is my books table.
[image]

Question 1: How to store book in database with multiple categories? Should I store category ids as a string value in database?

Question 2: How to query posts with multiple categories ?

This is my header.php code

```
<?php  include 'includes/db.php'; ?>
<html lang="fa-IR" dir="rtl">
   <head>
      <title>CMS کتابخانه</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" >
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" type="text/css" >
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" >
      <link href="./assets/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#">کتابخانه من</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/cms/' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/cms/index.php' ){echo 'active';} ?>">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">خانه <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
               دسته بندی
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <?php 
               $select_cat = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM book_category");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_cat)) {

                if(isset($_GET['category_name'])){
                  if($_GET['id'] == $row['category_id']){
                     $class='active';
                  }else{
                     $class='';
                  }
                }else{
                  $class='';
                }
                echo '<a class="dropdown-item '.$class.'" href="book_category.php?id='.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</a>';
                }
            ?>

              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">داغ ترین ها</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">نویسندگان</a>
            </li>
            <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) : ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="register.php">عضویت</a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="p-2"></div>
```

and this is my category.php for displaying specific categories posts.

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">آخرین کتاب ها</a>
        </nav>
         <article class="row">
            <section class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="card-columns">
            <?php 
               $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM books WHERE cat_id = ");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) :
            ?>
               <div class="card">
                 <img class="card-img-top rounded mx-auto d-block" src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>" width="199" height="312">
                 <div class="card-body text-right">
                  <h3 class="card-title"><a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></a></h3>
                  <p class="card-text"><?php echo mb_substr($row['description'],0,250); echo '...'; ?></p>
                   <a href="book.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">ادامه مطلب</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
         </section>
         <?php include 'includes/sidebar.php'; ?>
         </article>
      </div>
      <div style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have another table book_categories, where you store each book's different categories.

Comment: You have to create a second table which will connect the two other tables. And you should use the INNER JOIN inside your queries.

Comment: You should make a another table where you can add book id and category id. And get data using join with three tables

Comment: @JQuest i already have two tables , aren't they enough ? a book_categories table and books table.

Comment: @Nader-J I'm writing en example for you

Comment: @rawathemant three tables ? book_categories table, books table, and books_term for example ?

Comment: @JQuest thanks mate!

Comment: @Nader-J yes, you create another table like book_terms

Comment: @Nader-J I wrote an example with an example query with INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search the internet for *many to many* relationships:

One book may have zero or more categories. On the other side one category may have zero or more book relations. This relation is called *many to many*.

To archive this goal you have to add an mapping table:

```
table: book   table: book_category   table: category
==========    ====================   ===============
- id          - book_id              - id
- name        - category_id          - name
- author                             - ...
- ...
```

To query the data there are examples here [how to query many-to-many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832584/how-to-query-many-to-many).
You should find many examples for php in the internet ...

*Remark: OPs question switches between book and post entity. I decided to use book ... ;)*

## Edit 1:

OPs question in comment: *how to add row for submitted book ...?*

You have to know the relevant book and category ids. To connect a book to a catetory, you simply add the id's to the join table.

```
INSERT INTO book_category(book_id,category_id) values(40,50);
```

In this example the book with id 40 is joined to the category id 50.

If your question is targeting an php example, I can't tell you because I don't know how your DAO layer is implemented. But this should be a new question I guess.

Comment: but how to insert post with multiple category in database ?

Comment: when i submit a book ,it automatically submit book info in "book" table.
how to add row for submitted book in "book_category" ?

Answer (score 0):

If a book always has one category you can simply add a field `category_id` to your book's table, but when a book can have multiple categories and you don't know how much. You can do best by creating a second table that connects with multiple rows of multiple categories.

Create a table `books_category` with fields like `id`, `books_id`, `books_category_id`. Also make indexes on `books_id`, `books_category_id` for fast searching.

For your Query, you should use the `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM `books` INNER JOIN `books_category`  ON `books_category`.`books_id` =  `books`.`id` WHERE `books_category`.`books_category_id` = 5
```

Comment: @ChristophS He wants to display it inside a category page, so he should always have a category linked to a book. Otherwise, if he just want's every book with the category's on a book page the `LEFT JOIN` would be better.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment (and can't bring it back) when noticed you concrete category id inside your query.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Querying books for a kind of selected category you have to use `INNER JOIN`, to list all books (without category also) you have to use `LEFT JOIN` (sorry again for deleting my first comment to quickly ...)